# Unable to upload APK on play console getting (Upload a valid app bundle) issue - flutter

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, dart

I am getting an error while uploading apk to play console for first time.
I have released 2 apps with same account and did not get any error, but this is the 3rd app and it is working fine on each mode (--release, --debug, --profile).
I am building apk in flutter using --dart-define using the following command

```
flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi --no-tree-shake-icons --dart-define=ID=1234 --dart-define=APP_NAME=test_app --dart-define=APP_SUFFIX=.test
```

below is issue screenshot
[image]

Comment: You need to deploy aab only, apk is not allowed

Comment: But my previous apps accepting APK's, is there any specific setting that needs to be changed for uploading apk?

Comment: It was made compulsory from august. It was notified already.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was confused because my old apps still accepting APK's while updating the app, now I have successfully uploaded the .aab file to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not aware of google is stop accepting APK's for new app from august 2021 for reference please visit - [reference](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html)

```
flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons --dart-define=ID=1234 --dart-define=APP_NAME=test_app --dart-define=APP_SUFFIX=.test
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 16):

**Google Play store simply does not accepts APK anymore for publishing** the apps, you have to upload the [bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) of the Android app.

For [reference](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html)

**For Native Android**
Android Studio-> Build-> Generate Signed Bundle /APK...

[image]

**For Flutter**  See [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) and [dev doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle)

```
From the command line:

Enter cd [project]
Run flutter build appbundle
(Running flutter build defaults to a release build.)
```

Comment: Your answer is right but for building flutter app with --dart-define need different command

Comment: I mentioned `flutter build appbundle` in answer please check and also attach the link for

Answer (score 12):

You are uploading a `.apk` file in Google Play Console but you have to upload the `.aab` App Bundle file.

Comment: where it store?

Comment: `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab`

Answer (score 1):

You are required to upload an `App Bundle`, not the APK.

from developer console,

> Important: From August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger than 150 MB are now supported by either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset Delivery.

You can read more about this at [Android Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish).

You can use the below command to create an appBundle in flutter,

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Read more about Android deployment at [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Now it is mandatory to upload .aab file instead of .apk file on Google play store.
To Generate .aab file, please follow given steps.

1. Go to Build -- from top bar in Android studio
2. Click Generate Signed Bundle / Apk
3. Select Android App Bundle then Click Next
4. tick the check box for Export then Next

Answer (score 0):

For NativeScript users:

````
tns build android --release --aab --key-store-*...```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload aab and still got this message.
Try to rename your aab file name to something simple - do not include special characters